# Can I nest functions in JavaScript, and will they be called automatically?

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I'm working on a web form and had a quick question about Javascript functions. When the submit button is clicked, I'm supposed to make sure that all the required fields are filled out and that the correct type of information is entered into the appropriate fields. I know this is done by adding an onsubmit event to the form like this:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit=return validateForm()>
```

But since I will be checking for several different things, I was wondering if I can write multiple functions inside the validateForm() function, but have all those multiple functions run when I call validateForm()?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    function checkAge() {
        ----
    }
    function checkPhone() {
        ----
    }
}
```

If I were to do something like that, would my checkAge() and checkPhone() functions both run when I call the validateForm() function like this?:

```
onsubmit = return validateForm()
```

I know I could accomplish the same thing with multiple if statements inside the single validateForm() function, but the way I'm thinking seems better organized and easier if it's possible.

Comment: You can declare functions inside functions but they won't run unless you add some code to call them.

Comment: You're going to need quotes around your `onsubmit` attribute: `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @torazaburo, I was wondering why it wasn't working. Adding the quotes fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to declare them inside `validateForm` just to call them :

```
function checkAge() {
    //Check
}
function checkPhone() {
    //Check
}
function validateForm() {
    return checkAge() && checkPhone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to declare functions within functions.
What you probably want though is to define the function validateForm with calls to the checkAge and checkPhone functions, not to declare them inside.